# Is taking a picture with an electronic device permissable?

Tags: halal-haram, image

I try to understand this with my common sense and of course hadith and Quran al Karim.

When I talk about taking a picture of a living being, we're clearly not creating it, but kind of freeze the moment from a point of view. So if my mother takes a picture of my kids, it is just for watching them in times she misses them. She's not creating them.
Also, you can't watch it if you don't have suited tool that displays it.

If I want to draw a human, than there is a kind of trying to be a creator. That is disrespectful to our creator Allah (swt) and therefor a severe punishment will await me (a3udu bilah). Because I draw from my own imagination, thinking I can draw a human body.

Isn't the reason why images and statues are forbidden is because in ancient times people worshiped images and statues? Distracting them from Allah (swt)? Isn't that the main reason why Allah (swt) has forbidden them.

The reason I ask this is because some people say that taking a picture is forbidden. Some scholars also forbid taking pictures, with all respect for their knowledge, but I have issues with that fatwa as my common sense has difficulty to accept it.

Comment: please refer to this question http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/15038/6709

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here; your title is asking if taking a picture is haram, but your whole post pretty much concludes by pre-emptively disagreeing with anyone who says it *is*.  I'm honestly not sure what you're expecting in an answer here.

Comment: Well, imo because this question can't be answered with simply yes or no. It's actually a question without a context, so imo this question can have multiple answers in different contexts. If one asks "Is drinking water healthy?" You can say yes, but if you drink a lot of water (like 10 liters), it can be unhealthy.

Answer (score 0):

it only depends on niyaat.. so if ur niyat is good then it won't be haram ..and every hadiths have a history.. here all histories are related to worshipping anything by taking pictures or drawing creatures which ancient people did..but we're not doing these to those purposes..so it mightn't be haram as I think..Allah knows best...may Allah forgive me.

Comment: I agree with you, but we have to be careful with that. Idolizing is a form of worshiping too, so having a picture of a superstar on your bedroom's wall is from my understanding haram too. May Allah give us wisdom to make the right decision from our heart. Thank you for your post my brother.

Comment: Please try to provide authentic references to support your answer. Even though our Niyaat is good, what if those pictures are misused by others in later generations, Today we don't see the consequences. Think about it again.